# Spell Checker in Nutch 1.0

Tags: java, nutch

Can anyone tell me how to implement spell checker in nutch 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

[Can anyone tell me how to use the spell-check query plugin available in the contrib \ web2 dir (and even the rest of the plugins too)? Is it similar to enabling the nutch-plugins?](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/InstallingWeb2)

First hit at google (`nutch spell checker') and located on the apache nutch project pages...

Comment: I have reviewed the pages before I asked question.

The "contrib\web2" module is avaiable in nutch 0.9 but it didn't work in nutch 1.0. I tried to install this module in nutch 1.0 but it still not work...